# load a drop down box based on selected option in first drop down box

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to display a second drop down box based on selection i make in the drop down box 1
I am new to asp.net and using c# in asp.net and i am not aware of java script and jquery so i know html and CSS the code is as below:

```
      <asp:DropDownList ID="typeselect" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="typeselect_SelectedIndexChanged">
          <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="cash" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem Text="Traveller's cheque" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
      </asp:DropDownList>
```

When i select traveller's cheque from above code i want to get another drop down box differnt from the one when i select Cash. The following drop down box is default when cash is selected from above list items.

How can i display above code when user selects travellers cheque??
 kindly help me for implementing this..
Thank you in advance..

Comment: Do you want to achieve it using jQuery or C#?

Comment: Okay. Provided an answer below, please check

Answer (score 1):

in your `typeselect_SelectedIndexChanged event`.

```
    protected void typeselect_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       try{
        seconddropdown.Items.Clear();
        IList<InfoContainer> info = getInfoBasedOnSelected(typeselect.Value);
        seconddropdown.DataTextField = "name";
        seconddropdown.DataValueField = "value";
        seconddropdown.DataSource = info;
        seconddropdown.DataBind();
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
          throw new ApplicationException("ERROR :", ex);
        }
   }
```

and

don't forget to set set `AutoPostBack="True"` for `typeselect` dropdown

Comment: An empty catch block is a no-go!

Comment: whats that infocontainer you used in the above code..can u please brief me for what that class is meant and what data it should contain?

Comment: @user3181351 it should contain the details of the second dropdown based on the first dropdown value

Comment: @user3181351: you could also use sql query to retieve data instead of that if you need

Answer (score 1):

I think jQuery approach will be good for this as its not good to Postback whole thing for a single dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

You have atleast two options
1) Handle that typeselect_SelectedIndexChanged event (like you have done). See this page for more examples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx
Bad thing about this is that it will do post on server and refresh your page. If you want to avoid this you have to use option two.
2) Use ajax to fetch partial data of web page. I think this example should be close to yours need: [Partial postback of page with dropdownlist using AJAX on MVC3 page EF4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864864/partial-postback-of-page-with-dropdownlist-using-ajax-on-mvc3-page-ef4)

Answer (score 0):

Below link might hepls you(Cascading)

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2010/10/how-to-populate-dropdown-based-on-other.html

Answer (score 0):

Handle the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of you dropdown:

```
this.typeselect.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(typeselect_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

After that you can go to the `typeselect_SelectedIndexChanged` and check which value was selected. If it is 'Traveller's cheque' you can bind your second dropdown:

```
otherDropdown.DataTextField = "Name";
otherDropdown.DataValueField = "ID";
otherDropdown.DataSource = IList<T>;
otherDropdown.DataBind();
```